# Stored Procedure Returns zero results

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I developed a  search page containing a textbox control for entering a number and button to display the respective results in a Gridview. The page functions off a stored procedure. The sql query returns the expected results when ran via SQL Server Manager  when I manually type in the number, but when used in my stored procedure, I get zero results.

This is the code behind the button-event handler:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ShipperNotificationConnectionString1").ToString())
            Using command As New SqlCommand()
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.CommandText = "getPON"
                command.Connection = connection

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PON", txtPON.Text)

                connection.Open()
                Dim a As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                a.Fill(ds)
            End Using
        End Using

        gvPON.DataSource = ds
        gvPON.DataBind()
```

...The following is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPON]
(
    @PON varchar
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT     SupplierCompany.company_name, SupplierCompany.Address1, SupplierCompany.Address2, SupplierCompany.City, SupplierCompany.State, 
                      SupplierCompany.Zip, Shipment_Po.PONumber, Shipment.TotalWeight, Shipment.NoOfPallets, Shipment.PalletIdentical
FROM         SupplierCompany INNER JOIN
                      Shipment ON SupplierCompany.Company_guid = Shipment.Company_Guid INNER JOIN
                      Shipment_Po ON Shipment.Shipment_Guid = Shipment_Po.Shipment_guid
             WHERE Shipment_Po.PONumber = '''+ @PON +'''
END
```

...Could someone please provide some direction?

Comment: `Shipment_Po.PONumber = @PON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the stored procedure.  The expression:

```
         WHERE Shipment_Po.PONumber = '''+ @PON +'''
```

Is not doing what you think.  It is doing the following comparison:

```
         WHERE Shipment_Po.PONumber = '+@PON+'
```

Or something like that.  In other words, you are mixing dynamic SQL expressions with regular SQL.  Try doing:

```
         WHERE Shipment_Po.PONumber = @PON
```

If you are concerned about the cast to the right type:

```
         WHERE Shipment_Po.PONumber = (case when isnumeric(@PON) = 1 then cast(@PON as int) end)
```